# How do programming languages and protocols work in different languages (e.g. french, chinese)?

Tags: http, internationalization

I am wondering how programming languages and computer protocols work in different languages.  For instance, and HTTP GET request.  A required line in a GET request is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Those ASCII characters get translated into a specific string of bits.  So how does someone who speaks Chinese write a GET request?  They can't write GET in Chinese, because the bit string wouldn't match.

Comment: protocol is protocol for a purpose, it is same for chinese, french, english and australian language...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Answer (score 3):

They write it like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```